# How to manually select next focused index path in collection view

Tags: uicollectionview, uikit, tvos, uicollectionviewlayout, uifocusguide

How can I manually decide the next focused index path for my collection view on tvOS?

My use case is that I have a collection view with dynamic cells that scrolls in all directions, and sometimes when a cell in one section spans across several cells in the next one, I want to be able to manually decide what cell gets focused next.

The default behaviour seems to be that the collection view will select the cell in the middle of the previous one.

For example, the green cell is currently focused. When I navigate down, the collection view wants to focus the red cell, but I want the blue cell to be focused next.

[image]

My initial idea was to implement the `collectionView(_:shouldUpdateFocusIn:)` delegate function, and return `false` + trigger a focus update, when the collection view selects the "wrong" index path.

However, for some reason, `shouldUpdateFocusIn` gets called several times when I return `false` from it and causes a visible lag.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
    if let nextIndexPath = shouldFocusCell(context.focusHeading, (context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath, context.nextFocusedIndexPath)) {
        // The collection view did not select the index path of the cell we want to focus next.
        // Save the correct index path and trigger a focus update.
        lastFocusChange = (lastFocusChange.next, nextIndexPath)
        setNeedsFocusUpdate()
        // Using updateFocusIfNeeded() results in the following warning:
        // WARNING: Calling updateFocusIfNeeded while a focus update is in progress. This call will be ignored.
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Next idea was to do the same thing in `collectionView(_:didUpdateFocusIn:with:)`, but in this case we only update the focus after it has already moved to the "wrong" cell, so it becomes apparent to the user that the focus moves from the wrong cell to the correct one.

Not ideal either.

I'm using my own subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` and `UICollectionView`, but I don't see anything I can override to be able to manually decide what index path to focus next when navigating up/down/left/right before `shouldUpdateFocusIn` is called.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be to use `collectionView(_ collectionView:, canFocusItemAt:)` to let your collectionView know if a given indexPath can receive the focus.

You can find here below a naive implementation of this concept. You will need to adjust the maths on it to your needs.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    guard let currentlyFocusedCellLayoutAttributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: focusedIndexPath) else { return false }
    guard let cellAtGivenIndexPathLayoutAttributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) else { return false }
        
    let currentlyFocusedCellOriginX = currentlyFocusedCellLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x
    let currentlyFocusedCellOriginY = currentlyFocusedCellLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.y
    let currentlyFocusedCellWidth = currentlyFocusedCellLayoutAttributes.frame.width
        
    let cellAtGivenIndexPathOriginX = cellAtGivenIndexPathLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.x
    let cellAtGivenIndexPathOriginY = cellAtGivenIndexPathLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.y
    let cellAtGivenIndexPathWidth = cellAtGivenIndexPathLayoutAttributes.frame.width
            
    let offsetX = collectionView.contentOffset.x

    // Scrolling horizontally is always allowed
    if currentlyFocusedCellOriginY == cellAtGivenIndexPathOriginY {
        return true
    }
    
    // Scrolling vertically is only allowed to the first cell (blue cell in the screenshot)
    if cellAtGivenIndexPathOriginX <= offsetX {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David. However, I don't think this approach works exactly as I imagined. I only did a quick test of this, so please correct me if I'm wrong here. 

I want all the cells to be able to receive focus all the time. I just want to be able to control the order in which they receive it.

This way it seems like the focus will just skip over the cells if my logic decides that it’s not the “correct” one.

Comment: @anders all the cells will be able to receive the focus, this method will be called every time that the user triggers a gesture to move the focus from one cell to the next one. The focus manager, trying to find the next focusable view, will use the information provided by this method to determine if a cell can be chosen as focus destination.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve by using UICollectionView delegate protocol method, pls find code snippt.

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var sideMenuTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
let menueItem = ["Home", "Sports", "Movies", "Listen", "Play", "Game"]
let colors: [UIColor] = [.green, .blue, .purple, .orange, .yellow, .magenta, .brown, .black, .gray, .yellow, .green, .lightGray, .cyan, .magenta, .link, .blue, .yellow, .magenta, .brown, .black, .gray, .yellow, .green, .lightGray, .cyan, .magenta, .link, .blue]
var lastFocusedIndexPath: IndexPath?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    lastFocusedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
    initialConfiguration()
}

override var preferredFocusEnvironments : [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    return [collectionView]
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    updateTableViewContentInset()
}
    
func updateTableViewContentInset() {
    self.sideMenuTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -40, bottom:  0, right: 0)
}

func initialConfiguration() {
    sideMenuTableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "SideMenuTVCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SideMenuTVCell")
    sideMenuTableView.delegate = self
    sideMenuTableView.dataSource = self
    sideMenuTableView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    sideMenuTableView.isHidden = false
    
    collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "ColorCVCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ColorCVCell")
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
}
```

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return menueItem.count
}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SideMenuTVCell", for: indexPath) as! SideMenuTVCell
    cell.configureCell(string: menueItem[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return colors.count
}

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColorCVCell", for: indexPath) as! ColorCVCell
    cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(color: colors[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let previousIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath,
       let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: previousIndexPath) {
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
    }

    if let indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath,
       let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 8.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    }
            
    if let indexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { () -> Void in
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }
    }

    if let indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) { () -> Void in
            cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.1, y: 1.1)
        }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext) -> Bool {
    if let previouslyFocusedIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslyFocusedIndexPath) {
        let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width
        let cellWidth = cell.frame.width
        let rowCount = Int(ceil(collectionViewWidth / cellWidth))
        let remender = previouslyFocusedIndexPath.row % rowCount
        let nextIndex = previouslyFocusedIndexPath.row - remender + rowCount
        if let nextFocusedInndexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath {
            if context.focusHeading == .down {
                moveFocus(to: IndexPath(row: nextIndex, section: 0))
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}

private func moveFocus(to indexPath: IndexPath) {
    lastFocusedIndexPath = indexPath
    print(collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
        self.updateFocusIfNeeded()
    }
}

func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> IndexPath? {
    return lastFocusedIndexPath
}
```

}

Comment: How we can achieve same requirements in SwiftUI?